# Canadian Citizen and Non Resident for tax purposes

Tags: taxes, canada, non-resident, capital-gain, capital-gains-tax

I am a Canadian citizen was a non resident for tax purposes. If I sold stock shares in January 2016 and became officially a Canadian resident again in April 2016 (3 months after selling the stock), would I pay taxes on that capital gain when I file my 2016 taxes in 2017? Or, does the clock only start ticking once I was actually a resident again? Thank you

Comment: If the CRA agrees that you are non-resident for tax purposes (not a foregone conclusion) I don't see why you would pay any Canadian taxes on income realized while a non-resident- you'd pay taxes wherever you were resident.

Answer (score -1):

However, you might have to pay taxes on capital gains if these stocks were acquired during your prior residency.